# Question related to a bounded operator in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

The statement is "Let $A_n$ be a sequence in $B(H)$ and $A\in B(H)$ such that $\|A_n -A\|$ $\rightarrow 0$ and $n \rightarrow 0$ if $A_n$ is self adjoint then $A$ is also self-adjoint."

I understood the statement but I need one example for this.

Comment: Note that if $\langle x, A_n y \rangle = \langle A_n x, y \rangle$ for all $n$ then $\langle x, A y \rangle = \langle Ax, y \rangle$.

Comment: Presumably you meant $n \to \infty$? And an example is easy to come by, take $A_n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & {1 \over n} \\ {1 \over n} & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $A\to A^{\star}$ is  a continuous map. (Prove)

$A_n\to A\implies A_n^{\star}\to A^{\star}$

$A_n^{\star}=A_n$ and by uniqueness of limt $A^{\star}=A$